# WPF Windowstyle None + Create DropShadow using Native Windows API

Tags: wpf, window, dropshadow, window-style

I want to create a borderless Window via Windowstyle=None, but still want the default OS DropShadow effect.

I do NOT want to draw the border myself because i do NOT want to set AllowTransparency=True (the application runs on low end systems where this causes very bad performance of the application).

I do also NOT want to use third party Dlls that generate a "Shell" for me.

So what is want is to call the OS native API to draw its default border for me. I tried out this answer here [DropShadow for WPF Borderless Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372303/dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window) but this didnt work for window 8.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Edit: Using .NET 4.0 and the solution should support Windows 7 and Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

There is no native drop shadow in Windows 8. You can call the API but it won't do anything.

Metro flat design doesn't have drop shadow, unlike the glossy Vista and W7.

AFAIK without AllowsTransparency="True" you won't have that effect.