# Add DropShadow to a Custom made Window (Blend)

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

I am creating a custom Window form using **Blend**. (by setting `AllowTransparency` to `True`)

I've finished the design and it works pretty well. Now I want to add Shadow effect to it. (**DropShadowEffect**)

I can't do that because the Window itself is hidden so the effect won't show. And it doesn't work on the main Grid. No luck with adding a border and give the shadow to it.

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372303/dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window) is probably going to help you.

Comment: @DHN Thanks for the link, but the OP said he doesn't want the `AllowTransparency`. And the accepted answer code is based on a certain dll which doesn't give any control. Also, I want a Blend solution.

Comment: Ok, it was just a quick shot. Well I would suggest that you'd take the first visible element and give it a `DropShadow` effect. But I guess you've tried that already. ;o)

Comment: @DHN lol I think you should read everything first. ANyways, no matter what element you choose, they are all inside the Window control which is invisible due to the transparency. So any effect you apply is inside the window.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. ( With some help from this [page](http://nf2p.com/how-to/a-basic-borderless-wpf-window-with-bad-drop-shadow/) )

First of all, Set the window's `AllowTransparency` to `True`. Then change it's `Background` to `No Brush`

Lets say you have something like this: (Ignore the Rectangle and Borders)

[image]

Then change the Grid's `Background` to White color. Now click on your Window and Add about 15 pixels to its width and height.

[image]

And change the Shadow settings:

[image]

Now you can see the shadow :)

[image]

I think you got the idea how this is working. Remember you can still play around with the Window height/weight and the Shadow settings to get a better effect.

Comment: I can see you have found the solution after all :) +1