# DropShadow for WPF Borderless Window with win32 control hosted

Tags: wpf, interop

this issue is related to another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372303/dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window)

But if I have a win32 control hosted in WPF widnow, it mixed up with the glass effect, anyone have any ideas?

Sample code here: [Sample.zip](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D7D2416847E097A7!68660&authkey=!3VVVaXUtj88$)

Comment: see the sample image here: https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y2py67d-BYRDE8UhS9Ne-86GwLWvUBx1DG1ks2XIl3WnMQRtE8z8-IBGyXFqUiirQ_M2fq2yXB9mVj6vGsydw79zdlhqLlLXa6HYfyHmwCqUkU/sample.png?psid=1

Comment: I just find that if I set WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" , the transparent part will mask with the glass effect