# How to prevent shadow from hiding under window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this issue where I open an extra window with window.show() 
Which logically will draw on top of my first window(the part where the shadow is drawn).

But I want the new window to draw behind the shadow, or at least force the first window to redraw on top, so I don't get this effect that if I mouse over my original window the shadow pops back into view.

Any ideas? I tried window.focus() and window.Active(), window.show()..
Thanks!
http://i.imgur.com/GTes1NR.gifv

Comment: Does this help? [dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372303/dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window)

Answer (score 0):

add eventHandler onloaded for this new Window in first window and in this handler you can set Focus on first window (this)

```
window.Loaded += (sender, args) => this.Focus();
window.Show();
```

For me it works.