# Borderless window with shadow and blurbehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10

I tried `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` solution, and it worked well, but no shadows.
I tried combine blurbehind + apply shadow on window with [DropShadow for WPF Borderless Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372303/dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window)  but here i got issue with unfocus/focus window lost transparancy.
Is it possible to make borderless window with blurbehind + shadow (and some close/min/max)?
Example: AMD Radeon Settings. Is it wpf? Or custom c++ solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var accent = new AccentPolicy()
{
  AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_BLURBEHIND,
  AccentFlags = 0x20 | 0x40 | 0x80 | 0x100,
};
```

the set Value of AccentFlags will give your window a dropshadow effect like menu and calendar of Windows 10 does
[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try it. Is it possible to set custom shadow (color etc)?

Comment: Yes. It's working. Can i make glossy panels like <menu>?

Comment: @ionmike  Actually I'm referring from this [link]( http://pastebin.com/22nueJdZ ) you can see the  AccentFlags values is correspond to the four edge borders. Since this method using the native API of windows 10,I don't think there's much detailed effect tweaks could be done. However you can adjust the transparency and color of your application window to get a similar look as the <menu> of win10

Comment: This only works reliably if you set `AllowsTransparency` to true. You'll get glitches otherwise like the window not rendering until its resized.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do this in XAML, it's probably best to have all visual code in XAMl and logical code in C#.

Code:

//Set BorderThickness to 0 for no boreder
//play with DropDownShadowEffect

```
 <Border BorderBrush="color" BorderThickness="0" >
      <Border.Effect>
         <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Color="black" Direction="235" Opacity=".3" RenderingBias="Performance"  ShadowDepth="4" />
      </Border.Effect>
 </Border>
```

hope that is what you are looking for

Comment: I dont think it will work. Becouse you are trying to apply shadow to 'in window area' and can (or will) be blurred. There i'm trying to do native blurbehind+shadow on window (dwm).

Comment: @ionmike, ah yes, for what you want you probably would have to read up on control templates, as these allow you to change almost anything control wise, not sure about the actual window - sorry